# Android: lifecycle, onRestoreInstanceState not called when Phone turned

Tags: android

I use these functions in an activity class:
onSaveInstanceState
onRestoreInstanceState
onPause
onCreate

When the user starts the Activity onCreate gets called, when the user ends, onPause gets called. Thats fine so far.

But when the user rotates the phone, 
onPause
onSaveInstanceState
onCreate
gets called. I would have expected onRestoreInstanceState before onCreate. Why is this so and how should I handle initialization of ui-data if not there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would have expected onRestoreInstanceState before onCreate.

The [documentation for `onRestoreInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) clearly states:

> This method is called after onStart() when the activity is being re-initialized from a previously saved state, given here in savedInstanceState. Most implementations will simply use onCreate(Bundle) to restore their state, but it is sometimes convenient to do it here after all of the initialization has been done or to allow subclasses to decide whether to use your default implementation.

If you wish to initialize your UI with stuff from the `Bundle` in `onCreate()`, feel free to do so.

Comment: documentation says:
"This method is called after onStart() when the activity is being re-initialized from a previously saved state, given here in savedInstanceState."
Thats strage, because when I turn the phone onSaveInstanceState gets called but not this method. I need this method because I want to destinguish between normal start (new init of the ui) and a interrupt like phone turn (ui should look the same as before)

Comment: @user1324936: Correct. If there is no previously saved state (i.e., the `Bundle` passed to `onCreate()` is `null`), then `onRestoreInstanceState()` is not called.

Comment: when phone is turned onCreate gets a Bundle != null, if started from scrach the Bundle is null. Somehow strange that onRestoreInstanceState() is never called

Comment: @user1324936: "when phone is turned onCreate gets a Bundle != null" -- no, it does not.